# PostgreSQL : Difference between ItemIdData & CTID

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

According to postgres documentation :

`ItemIdData` is an Array of item identifiers pointing to the actual items. Each entry is an (offset,length) `pair`.

&

`CTID` is The physical location of the row. and this is also `pair`.

Please help to understand that whether both are same?

Thanks ..!

Comment: Can you link that "postgres documentation" please? I cannot find the quoted sentences anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find only one mention of `ItemIdData` in the postgres docs, and that is in the [*Database Page Layout* section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html). It explains the difference quite well:

> Every table […] is stored as an array of pages of a fixed size.
>
> Following the page header are item identifiers (`ItemIdData`), each
> requiring four bytes. **An item identifier contains a byte-offset to the
> start of an item, its length in bytes, and a few attribute bits which
> affect its interpretation**. […] Because an item identifier is never
> moved until it is freed, its index can be used on a long-term basis to
> reference an item, even when the item itself is moved around on the
> page to compact free space. In fact, **every pointer to an item
> (`ItemPointer`, also known as `CTID`) created by PostgreSQL consists
> of a page number and the index of an item identifier**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So no, they're not the same.